# Can I find out how many pages have been printed by a printer?

Tags: history, brother-printer

I want to know how many pages have been printed. Is there any way?

I am using Brother HL 5350DN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On our HL5250DN I can go to the printer's IP in a web browser which pulls up various information.  Under Maintenance Information there is a page count.

Comment: sorry buddy , i have checked that mine is 5240DN , it does not have network feature. Can i still access thta page

Comment: I find that there are **way** more settings, statistics and configurations available when you access the printer via it's IP address. Mine isn't a WiFi enabled printer either but I 'share' it with my network, using a homegroup. Then when I right click the printer (in devices and printers), select properties. Web Services tab > It lists the IP address of the printer.

I can print a config page, cleaning page, adjust settings, etc... It lists total jobs completed. Sleep times, average job size even total In/Out jams. The level of config you'd never get from the base OS properties.

Comment: hey, @BiTinerary how to share my USB printer with my network? I mean I have shared my printer with my homegroup but still don't have the tab "web services" in properties as you said. please tell me about the detailed process. I have the same problem(need to know how many pages has been printed by my printer) so I wanna know it.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to print out the printer settings page, not the test page

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/eu/gb/en/faq/faq/000000/000500/000071/faq000571_000.html?reg=eu&prod=hl5250dn_all&c=gb&lang=en

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact question as you and the same printer.  It's taken a half hour to get the answer but I just tried it and it worked:

1. From your computer, go to "Start", the "printers and faxes"
2. Select Brother HL-5250DN by double-clicking it on the list of printers you have.
3. From the top select the "printer" command
4. Select "printer preferences".
5. Along the top, pick the "support" tab.
6. Hit "Print Settings"
7. Look on the pages that print out. Halfway down page 2 it gives the "page count".  Mine was 7102.

Prior to this, I had removed the toner cartridge and taped over the "sensor eyes" on the far right and left side so the printer would stop telling me it was out of toner.  I found this idea on the Internet and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Do a print test, which prints out a page with information on drum life, pages printed etc. The print test option can be accessed by going to the printer options from the control panel, or when you are printing you can access some form of advanced options.

I know not yet of any way to get it via software for my Brother 2400.

Comment: i printed the test page but there is no information regarding paper on that

Answer (score 0):

If you have PostScript enabled, you can get the pagecount from the statusdict dictionary.  You need a bidirectional connection to the printer, either over the net or from the host to which it is attached.  The [PostScript FAQ](http://www.postscript.org/FAQs/language/node3.html) has some information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Put the printer in the Service Mode and print the maintenance information page.

1. Begin with the power switch in the off position and with the front
   cover open.
2. Press and hold the "Go" button and then turn the power switch to the
   on position. All LEDs should light.
3. When the Status LED turns off after a couple of seconds, release the
   "Go" button. All LEDs should turn off.
4. Press the "Go" button twice. About a second later, the Toner, Drum,
   and Paper LEDs should then light.
5. Press the "Go" button once more and then close the front cover. A
   list of maintenance information (including page count and also
   remaining life of drum and toner cartridge) should be printed.